# How to send my data when the user device come online

Tags: java, android, android-studio, synchronization

I have an android application that has some data from user steps count and I want to send the user steps counts to sever when the user device comes online even if the user is not in my application.
What is the best way to tackle that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On high-level the solution should look like next at my point f view:

- Create receiver to get connectivity changing broadcasts. This should look like this

  ```
  public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

      @Override
      public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

          if(checkInternet(context))
          {
              Log.d("InternetLog", "Network Available Do operations",Toast.LENGTH_LONG); 
              //Do your background task here
          } 

      }

      boolean checkInternet(Context context) {
          ServiceManager serviceManager = new ServiceManager(context);
          if (serviceManager.isNetworkAvailable()) {
              return true;
          } else {
              return false;
          }
      }
  ```

  }
- Be sure to register it in manifest also

  `<receiver android:name=".NetworkChangeReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />.
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>`

  - After this is done, your application is ready to awake on connectivity change.
  - I recommend to use some background task to use data to the server, you should take a look at [services component](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services?hl=en) or [work manager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)
  - Depending on what way you will choose just implement inside backend connecting logic and start background task in your receiver, just replace the comment with propper code

**Update**

As alternative, instead of `ServiceManager` you can use this method

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {     
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo(); 
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

You will also need in your **Manifest**

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Comment: Hey bro,
how should I use ServiceManager I cant import it?
is there anything else I can use instead.

Comment: Excuse how should I tackle it to run when the application is close and the user is not in my application. Because when I tested your solution it just ran when the application is open.

Comment: Hey, I believe you should update receiver in manifest with this tag `android:enabled = true`